# setParent addChild does not seems to refresh children position in cocos2d-x 3.6

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, ccsprite, ccnode

I want to change the parent of sprite, using oldparent->removeChild(child) from the old parent node, and then child->setParent(newparent) in the child sprite, passing the new parent as param. also tried with newparent->addChild(child).

The issue is that the position of the child does not change after that operation. I expect to see the child sprite changing its position to a new position relative to the parent transform. 
Is this the expected behavior or I need to call some update method to force a refresh of the child transform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last night I finally discover the problem. It happens after I decided to add a child->removeFromParentAndCleanup() before adding the child to a new parent.
at this point, the program chrashed with no more clues in gdb.
That make me suspect of a invalid memory issue.. (maybe the child was going erased in the background when it sees it is orphan?): so I try with:

```
  child->retain();
  child->removeFromParent();
  newparent->addChild(child);
  child->release();
```

and both the crash and the problem with the update of the relative position had gone!